# On symfony 1.4 default route overrides custom routes

Tags: routes, overriding, symfony-1.4

I got this problem: I'm adding two new routing rules **at the top of the list** to 'apps/frontend/config/routing.yml', here they are:

```
topics_page:
 url: /topics/:slug/
 param: {module: topics, action: page}
 requirements: {slug: .+ }

topics:
 url: /topics
 param: {module: topics, action: index}
```

The second rule shoots out when called:

```
http://test.site.com/topics/
Match route "topics" (/topics) for /topics with parameters array ( 'module' => 'topics', 'action' => 'index',)
```

...but the first route doesn't shoot at all:

```
Match route "default" (/:module/:action/*) for /topics/75669 with parameters array ( 'module' => 'topics', 'action' => '75669',)
```

'default' is the last item in the routing list.

What could be the possible cause of such behavior and how to make it work correctly?

P.S. cache is Memcached, maybe it has something to do with it?

Comment: Did you try the URL `/topics/75669/`. Note the last trailing slash. I noted that your route `topics_page` it is defined with trailing slash at the end.

Comment: Yep, sure.
Also, there's a nginx redirect to close the trailing slash so I get it anyways.
Also note that the rule /topics is without the slash but it gets the route /topics/ correctly.

Moreover, there are several rules below in the list, like 
/home/:slug 
/tag/:slug 
that do work.